# A car with mass 840 Kg is rolling at 50ms^-1 and is suddenly opposed by a friction force of 120N

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

> A car with mass 840 Kg is rolling at 50ms^-1 and is suddenly opposed by a friction force of 120N.
>
> a) Find the Acceleration.
>
> b) How long does it take the car to stop.
>
> c) How far does the car travel before it stops.

Hi,
Can someone help me with this question. I can do Part b) and c) if i find acceleration but I'm not sure how should i find the acceleration. Maybe you guys can help me out where should i start.

Comment: This is a little too much of a homework question

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: This is a standard drill problem designed to make you think about what you have heard in class or read in your reading assignment.  Go to your teacher for help with these kinds of simple puzzles. They are better equipped to help you face to face with drill problems like this.

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Acceleration is $\frac{force}{mass}$. See what values you are given.

Comment: Thanks. I know this formula but i don't have force. Can you give me a hint how should i find force here.

Comment: @Rahul "is suddenly opposed by a friction **force** of 120N". It is directly stated.

Comment: what do you mean by that ??

Comment: @Rahul The exercise says that the force is 120N, so you have the force

Comment: but isin't it frictional force

Comment: @Rahul That is correct. That is the force that acts on the car. Use that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/117839)

Comment: @JonCuster Is is really more I can say about that homework question? :)

Comment: There are only a few canned replies available. It is better to let the question be closed - if you help they come back with other HW questions - we want them to think deeper and ask good questions...